# How do I expand StirlingS2[n, 10] in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: functions, symbolic, combinatorics, integer-sequence

I know that it is possible to expand `StirlingS2[n, 10]` in terms of elementary functions of `n`. I tried `FunctionExpand` but it returned unevaluated:

```
In[1]:= FunctionExpand[StirlingS2[n, 10]]
Out[1]= StirlingS2[n, 10]
```

Is there a way to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Try `FunctionExpand[StirlingS2[n, 10], Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify assumptions:

```
In[1]:= FunctionExpand[StirlingS2[n, 10], n > 0 && Mod[n, 1] == 0]
Out[1]= -(1/362880) + 2^(-8 + n)/315 + 1/135 2^(-7 + 2 n) + 
 1/315 2^(-8 + 3 n) - 3^(-3 + n)/1120 + 
 1/5 2^(-7 + n) 3^(-3 + n) - 5^(-2 + n)/576 + 
 1/567 2^(-8 + n) 5^(-2 + n) - 7^(-1 + n)/4320 - 9^(-2 + n)/4480
```