# Warning and Errors during Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, warning-messages, version-7

I defined a compiled function

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
   z = (n^x); 
   Binomial[n, #]* StirlingS2[x, #] *(#!)/z & /@ Range[x]];
```

and I want to run this for

```
n = 300000.0;
x = 186200;
Timing[cf[x, n]]
```

But I have below warnings/errors:

```
Join::heads: Heads CurrentValue and List at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.
Join::heads: Heads CurrentValue and List at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.
Join::heads: Heads CurrentValue and List at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.
general:stop : Futher output of Join::heads will be suppressed during this calculation.
CompileFunction::cfse : Compiled expression
949792642757151450284577945707701821742626866813<<1019743>>\
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 should be a \
machine-size integer.
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 2; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation
```

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Because for this values of `n` and `x` this compile function should be evaluated fast, but it is working very slow.

Comment: No idea, but a) since `z` isn't localised with `Module` you'll end up calling the main evaluator anyway, and even if you do localize it, b) neither `Binomial` nor `StirlingS2` are compilable. You can see a list of compilable functions with ``Compile`CompilerFunctions``

Comment: As `x` and `n` are integers, one might get this working.

Comment: Can you give more details on these parameter and explain a litte bit, what you are trying do? You can use ´FunctionExpand[Binomial[n, m]]´ to get the function definition of `Binomial` in terms of the `Gamma` function, which is compilable. For StirlingS2 you could use the definitions from [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS2/) or [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24893/how-do-i-expand-stirlings2n-10-in-terms-of-elementary-functions) to get something compilable.

Comment: Could you also add an expacted output, because the function, as it is defined in you question, would have an output that is a list of 186200 numbers. A lot of these smaller than `$MinMachineNumber` and therefore not suitable within `Compile`

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues here. My oldest *Mathematica* here is version 8, but when I look at your compiled code:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}}, z = (n^x);
   Binomial[n, #]*StirlingS2[x, #]*(#!)/z & /@ Range[x]];

<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[cf]
```

I see that there are several callbacks from the compiled code to the main-kernel, because e.g. `Binomial`, `StirlingS2` or `Factorial` cannot be compiled. I would make no sense to compile your function.

You biggest issue seems to be that you think compiled functions can work with arbitrary large integers like *Mathematica* can. They cannot! The numbers in a compiled call are the usual machine numbers like C style `int` or `float`. This is what the message

> Compiled expression .... should be a "machine-size integer"

tries to tell you. Here, I'm not sure whether this integer is really too large to fit, because your code doesn't localize the variable `z`. With a proper definition

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}}, Module[{z = (n^x)},
   Binomial[n, #]*StirlingS2[x, #]*(#!)/z & /@ Range[x]]
  ]

n = 300000.0;
x = 186200;
Timing[cf[x, n];]
```

I only get the message

> Numerical error encountered at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

which is comes from the calculation of `n^x`, because this number is too large with the values you have supplied. You should use normal *Mathematica* code to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason for that particular error could also be that `n` is of type Real, but was defined as Integer in the cf.

Comment: @Karsten7. No, usually numbers like `1.0` are just converted to integer by casting: `Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, x][300.0]`
On the other hand, when the conversion is not possible a message is thrown: `Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, x][300.1]`
The message in the example is thrown because `z` is not localized by `Module`. After that the call `cf[3, 300.]` runs without message.

Comment: @Karsten7. I have added this information to the answer, because my first version did not describe the issue properly.